# Richtextbox mousemove event what color the text is

Tags: c#, colors, richtextbox, mousemove

Is there a way to determine what color the text is in a `RichTextBox` using the `mousemove` event? I would like to avoid using `Richtextbox.Select` because it adds a little select bar everywhere the mouse moves.

```
private void rtbComputerstatus_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int c = rtbComputerstatus.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

    rtbComputerstatus.Select(c, 1);

    if (rtbComputerstatus.SelectionColor == Color.Blue)
        rtbComputerstatus.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    else
        rtbComputerstatus.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

Comment: If you change `rtbComputerstatus.Select(c, 1);` to `rtbComputerstatus.Select(c, 0);` then you at least don't get the big blue selection box, even if you do get the caret following your mouse around the box.

Comment: That could work, would there be a way to hide the caret only when inside the rich text box ?

Comment: Possibly.  I know it can be done using Windows APIs.  Honestly, though, you're better off going with Mark Hall's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, modified from this [MSDN Forum answer of JoOls](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/e9fa7401-890a-4489-ad29-0cc00f6b7cc0), It will give you the color of the pixel that is under the Mouse.

```
private void rtbComputerstatus_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point  cursorPoint = Cursor.Position;
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    Graphics g  = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
    g.CopyFromScreen(cursorPoint, new Point(), new Size(1, 1));
    Color pixelColor = bm.GetPixel(0, 0);
    g.Dispose();
    bm.Dispose();
    if (pixelColor.ToArgb().Equals(Color.Blue.ToArgb()))
    {
        if (rtbComputerstatus.Cursor != Cursors.Hand)
            rtbComputerstatus.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }
    else
    {
        if(rtbComputerstatus.Cursor != Cursors.Default)
            rtbComputerstatus.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 this works when I test it locally.  I was trying to figure out a solution like this one when you posted it.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that works when my mouse is over a blue pixel in the Richtextbox but when the mouse moves into the white spaces between letters, it goes back to the normal cursor. It seems like it is Too accurate on the pixel, would increasing the bitmap (1,1) increase its "size" ?

Comment: Yes it would but even if you did you are still just testing 1 pixel, in this case the upper left hand corner. You would need to check all of them to see if the majority were blue. I am trying to work on a solution that would cut down the sensitivity of the MouseMove Logic

Comment: in my case, i know what my blue text will say: "Click to RDP"

could i get the pixel width and height of that string and use that as the bitmap size then loop through each pixel and if the loop detects anything blue, stop the loop and change the cursor to the hand ? if that makes sense

Comment: Yes you could do that, but your main problem is that your MouseMove event is extremely noisy, it generates multiple Events in a short period of time. You may want to do something like trigger a timer on the MouseEnter Event put the above logic in it and stop it on the MouseLeave event. I am not sure exactly what you want your end result to be or what you are wanting to do once you detect your text, so it is a little hard to be more specific.

Comment: thanks for you advice so far Mark, I'm basically having a rich text box show the result of a pinged computer. If that machine is online, it will show the "Computer is Online.........Click to RDP". I want the "Click to RDP" to look and act like a hyperlink. I have methods in my program to color Online green and Click to RDP blue if it detects those strings. Since RichTextBox's don't support links with arbitrary text, I had to do some fiddling. Everything works great except i would like to show a hand cursor if the user mouses over anything blue. This would create a hyperlink-esque effect.

Comment: "Since RichTextBox's don't support links with arbitrary text" See if this article helps you out: [Links with arbitrary text in a RichTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox)

Comment: I tried that as well. It works and inserts a link but the problem is when I insert a new line into the richtextbox with another link, the old link turns to plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but would the following work?

```
    private void rtbComputerstatus_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rtbComputerstatus.ForeColor.ToKnownColor() == KnownColor.Blue)
            rtbComputerstatus.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        else
            rtbComputerstatus.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

I think this will check just the selected text:

```
    private void rtbComputerstatus_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (rtbComputerstatus.SelectionColor.ToKnownColor() == KnownColor.Blue)
            rtbComputerstatus.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        else
            rtbComputerstatus.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

    }
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think `ForeColor` is a global attribute of the RichTextBox.  It doesn't give you the colour at that position.

Comment: That's unfortunately exactly what he's trying to avoid in his original question.

Comment: Not on my machine it doesn't.  It's not selecting any text, just checks the selected text.  When I run his test code, i do get text being selected, which is what I thought he was trying to avoid.  My code doesn't select anything, just checks if what is selected is "Blue".

Comment: In which case it will never check what's currently under the mouse cursor, which is what he's trying to do.  It'll only ever check the text at the current caret position.

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess I had an alternate interpretation of what the OP was after.  I'll kindly step out of the way :)

Comment: Thanks sous2817, indeed i am trying to avoid the using the selecting way as it adds a little block of selection everywhere the mouse goes lol. I posted it in to show what i currently had.